# Eclipse:Installation failed with An Error

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, eclipse-jee

When I try to install the installation finish with an error : installation failed with an error - show log.My PC is 64-Bit and my jdk and the installer too, so its not the problem.

```
[2020-04-04 15:23:41] Downloading org.eclipse.platform_root
[2020-04-04 15:23:41] Downloading org.eclipse.platform.ide.executable.win32.win32.x86_64
[2020-04-04 15:23:41] Downloading org.eclipse.rcp_root
[2020-04-04 15:23:41] Collected 3 artifacts for http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020- 
03/202003181000 in 0.688s
[2020-04-04 15:23:52] An error was detected while performing the engine operation and the changes are 
being rolled back. See the log for details.
[2020-04-04 15:23:52] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=4 An error occurred during the 
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase.
at org.eclipse.oomph.util.OomphPlugin.coreException(OomphPlugin.java:280)
at 
org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:550)
at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:342)
at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:903)
at 
org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer
.jav  a:3827) at 
org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.
java:3755)
at 
org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks
(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3736)
at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3629)
at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform
(SimpleVariablePage.java:1342)
at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$32
(SimpleVariablePage.java:1204)
at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$20.run
(SimpleVariablePage.java:1149)
ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 session context was:(profile=C__Users_PC_eclipse_jee- 
2020-038_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust, operand=, action=).
ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 Error reading signed content.
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignatureBlockProcessor.readFully
(SignatureBlockProcessor.java:508)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignatureBlockProcessor.readIntoArray
(SignatureBlockProcessor.java:490)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignatureBlockProcessor.processSigner
(SignatureBlockProcessor.java:101)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignatureBlockProcessor.process
(SignatureBlockProcessor.java:76)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedBundleFile.initializeSignedContent
(SignedBundleFile.java:47)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedBundleHook.getSignedContent
(SignedBundleHook.java:223)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.checkCertificates
(CertificateChecker.java:77)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.start(CertificateChecker.java:58)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust.completePhase(CheckTrust.java:55)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.postPerform(Phase.java:254)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:105)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:50)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:80)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:48)
at 
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.director.PlanExecutionHelper.executePlan 
(PlanExecutionHelper.java:46)
at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransaction
```

My PC is 64-Bit and my jdk and the installer too, so its not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error log suggests that jar file seems to be corrupted.

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
```

In mac:

Try accessing `About Eclipse > Installation Details > Installation History` in eclipse and revert to stable last configuration. Once done, restart eclipse and try the installation again.

[image]

Comment: I didn't find Installation Details.where can I find it?

Comment: I have added a screenshot.

Comment: but i don't found installation details in eclipse installer